# controller value "null" problem. Laravel/Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

I am sending params to controller from Vue by axios, below.

```
getMarkers: function() {
        let bounds = this.map.getBounds();

        let southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
        let northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

        axios.get('/ajax', {
            params: {
                fromLat: southWest.lat()-0.05,
                toLat: northEast.lat()-0.05,
                fromLng: southWest.lng()+0.05,
                toLng: northEast.lng()+0.05,
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data;
            this.updateMarkers();
        });

},
```

and then getting this data in controller.

```
public function ajax(Request $request){
    $fromLat = $request->get('fromLat');
    $toLat = $request->get('toLat');
    $fromLng = $request->get('fromLng');
    $toLng = $request->get('toLng');


    $data = \DB::table('allestates')
      ->where('lat', '>', $fromLat)
      ->where('lat', '<', $toLat)
      ->where('lng', '>', $fromLng)
      ->where('lng', '<', $toLng)
      ->get();

      $response = response()->json($data);
      return $response;

}
```

the problem start here. When I check my endpoint(which is "`/ajax`") I am having and error.

> Illegal operator and value combination.

this, because `$fromLat` etc... is being null at that time?. check the [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvKEc.jpg)

But map and markers are working fine. though, I can't see the data in the page, till I move the map and see the all markers. Then data being visible in the page too. But endpoint still giving an error.

thank you for helping!

Comment: Then the value must be NULL and you can perform that operation on NULL value. You need to check the value before adding the where condition.

Comment: could you give me an example for that? @somsgod

Comment: can you post the values you are getting for these 
$fromLat = $request->get('fromLat');
$toLat = $request->get('toLat');
$fromLng = $request->get('fromLng');
$toLng = $request->get('toLng');

Answer (score 0):

```
    getMarkers: function() {
    let bounds = this.map.getBounds();

    let southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    let northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

    var from_lat = "";
    if(southWest.lat() != null) {
        from_lat = southWest.lat()-0.05;
    }


    axios.get('/ajax', {
        params: {
            fromLat: from_lat,
            toLat: northEast.lat()-0.05,
            fromLng: southWest.lng()+0.05,
            toLng: northEast.lng()+0.05,
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        this.estates = response.data;
        this.updateMarkers();
    });

    },
```

Try this

Comment: public function ajax(Request $request){
    $fromLat = $request->get('fromLat');
    $toLat = $request->get('toLat');
    $fromLng = $request->get('fromLng');
    $toLng = $request->get('toLng');


    $data = \DB::table('allestates');
    if($fromLat != null) {
      $data = $data->where('lat', '>', $fromLat);
    }
    $data = $data->where('lat', '<', $toLat)
      ->where('lng', '>', $fromLng)
      ->where('lng', '<', $toLng)
      ->get();

      $response = response()->json($data);
      return $response;

}    please try this

Comment: No change same error at same the same line. like in the question I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can check for null or certain values and then do conditional queries:

```
$query  = \DB::table('allestates');

if ($fromLat != NULL && $fromLat != ''){
   $query->where('lat', '>', $fromLat);
}
if ($toLat != NULL && $toLat != ''){
   $query->where('lat', '>', $toLat);
}
if ($fromLng != NULL && $fromLng != ''){
   $query->where('lng', '>', $fromLng);
}
if ($toLng != NULL && $toLng != ''){
   $query->where('lng', '>', $toLng);
}

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: first, no problem at the endpoint. returns all data! it's good but the main page. I only see three data? and when I open the map I see no data?? this is getting awkward.. by the way the answer for your earlier question. $fromLat or etc... returns `null` that's why I delete `&& " "` part